# Difficulty with nested while loops in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a pause function for a looping script and this is the structure I have set up:

```
global_run = True
while global_run is True:
  run = bool(info from a text file)
  print(run)
  print(type(run))
  while run is True:
    RUN ACTUAL SCRIPT
    run = bool(info from a text file)
```

The point is so that I can edit the text file to set a condition to True or False based on whether I want to keep the script running. The code above only runs the script once. When I check how things are running, the script runs one loop and then prints:

```
True
<class 'bool'>
```

However, it just stops right then and there. I am not understanding. If run is a True boolean value, should't the nested while loop run? It doesn't.

Comment: `run is True` or `run is False`  it is a true boolean ... however its worth noting `bool("False") is True`

Comment: is there any output in your "actual script"? It could be executing without you knowing.

Comment: What, exactly is `bool(info from a text file)`?  This incomplete example doesn't specify your problem.  Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: The script itself is a complex Selenium script so that's why I omitted it. It was running fine before I added the structure in my question to give it a pause ability. The info from text file is returning as True and as a boolean, but it is not triggering the nested while loop to run.

Comment: im pretty sure it is triggering ...you can verify with `bool("TRUE") is True`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely `Actual Script`, not the code you provided.

For example, the following code works without problem.

```
run = True
print(run)
print(type(run))
while run is True:
  print("Running")
  run = False
```

`Running` successfully prints. Therefore, the issue is not with the loop.

To confirm, `print("Running")` before you start running `Actual Script` to check if it enters the nested loop.

Comment: Humm. Okay. The script was running fine before I added this structure but I will take a closer look.

Comment: maybe you have mixed tabs and spaces? you can check for this with `python -t myscript.py` (I think thats the switch)

Comment: @WTBHelbreath Yea. Double check by printing before running the script. Maybe there's a reused variable?